# Increasing value of sched_latency_ns and sched_min_granularity_ns

Tags: linux, scheduling, latency, performance-tuning

Why do I get an error message when I try to increase the values of these two parameters:

```
#cat /proc/sys/kernel/sched_latency_ns
1000000000
#echo 2000000000 > /proc/sys/kernel/sched_latency_ns
bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
#
```

I get the same error when I replace sched_latency_ns by sched_min_granularity_ns.

Can someone tell me the correct way to increase these parameters.

Answer (score 3):

One second is the absolute maximum accepted value for that setting. Values more than 1000000000 are not valid (the number of nanoseconds in one second).

See [the kernel source code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sysctl.c#L262)

```
262 static int max_sched_granularity_ns = NSEC_PER_SEC;     /* 1 second */
```

and

[line 294](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sysctl.c#L294)

```
294         {
295                 .procname       = "sched_latency_ns",
296                 .data           = &sysctl_sched_latency,
297                 .maxlen         = sizeof(unsigned int),
298                 .mode           = 0644,
299                 .proc_handler   = sched_proc_update_handler,
300                 .extra1         = &min_sched_granularity_ns,
301                 .extra2         = &max_sched_granularity_ns,
302         },
```

Larger and larger values have a diminishing improvement on performance. Excessively high values can cause issues. One second is already an extremely high setting.